# TypeError: self.options.theme is undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have included jquery noty in my project but I get the following error `TypeError: self.options.theme is undefined` in this line of in the js file `self.options.theme.style.apply(self);`
I have googled but no success.

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Send").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "RetrievePassword.aspx/SendNewPassword?email=" + $("#Email").val(),
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {
                    //alert(result.d);
                    var n = noty({
                        text: 'A new password has been mailed', theme: 'default', layout: 'center', type: 'success', timeout: 3000, callback: {
                            onClose: function () {
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    window.location.href = 'Login.aspx';
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    var n = noty({ text: "An error occurred, either the email does not exists or is incorrect.", theme: 'default', layout: 'center', type: 'error', timeout: 2000 });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you include all the necessary JS files for Noty, I would suspect you have not specified a theme:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/jquery.noty.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/layouts/top.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/layouts/topLeft.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/layouts/topRight.js"></script>
<!-- You can add more layouts if you want -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/themes/default.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is what I have referenced:
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/noty/jquery.noty.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/noty/themes/default.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/noty/layouts/center.js"></script>

Comment: Can you post where this code is located so I can take a look?

Comment: I was trying to see the actual errors being produced, can't really do that with just your source.

Comment: Do you need my HTML as well?

Comment: Is it hosted somewhere online?

Comment: try leaving out the theme parameter in the `noty()` call